# Android build fails - Diagnostic , ImagePicker plugin dependency mismatch

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on my ionic 3 project which was building perfectly until it decided not to. When I run `ionic run android` , it fails with

> BUILD FAILED
>
> Error: /home/raj/ionic/bookemon/platforms/android/gradlew: Command
>   failed with exit code 1 Error output: Note: Some input files use or
>   override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for
>   details. Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>
> /home/raj/ionic/bookemon/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:3:
>   AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches
>   the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
>
> /home/raj/ionic/bookemon/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:4:
>   AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches
>   the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
>
> /home/raj/ionic/bookemon/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:3:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
>
> /home/raj/ionic/bookemon/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:4:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
>
>   > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Such cases mostly occurs when there is a mismatch between sdk platform and build tool. But I have installed `25` latest version of both.

The build is successful when I dont have two plugins, `Diagnostic` and `ImagePicker`. Both dont work well together. If I add only one of them The build succeeds.

I have the latest `android@6.2.1` platform. Please let me know if you need anymore info. I am really stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took some time to understand the issue. It was due to dependency mismatch in a library which both plugins use - `AppCompat` . ImagePicker has pinned it to 23 . So as a temporary fix I have forked diagnostic plugin to use version 23. Here is the [repo](https://github.com/rajeevriitm/cordova-diagnostic-plugin).

An issue is open on both repos, a fix has to come from `Imagepicker` .

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/issues/203

https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/ImagePicker/issues/51